# Checking collisions with a line and a rectangle

Tags: java, collision-detection

Is it possible to check a collision with a line using an Area object?

Currently the way I am doing it is not working:

This returns false when you run it. But the line is very clearing touching the rectangle, in fact its completely inside it.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

public class collision {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Area area1 = new Area(new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100));
    Area area2 = new Area(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100));

    System.out.println(isColliding(area1, area2));
}

public static boolean isColliding(Area area1, Area area2) {
    if (area2 != null) {
        Area collide1 = new Area(area1);
        collide1.subtract(area2);
        if (!collide1.equals(area1)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}

}
```

Comment: Keeping in mind that a Line2D is really just a very-thin rectangle, couldn't you use this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Area.html#intersects(java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D)

Comment: Ill try it, I didn't know Line2D was a rectangle, considering it is rotated (right?)

Comment: @Kon Are you sure `Line2D` is a rectangle--i.e. it has the same behaviors as a `Rectangle2D`?  Or are you speaking in a general sense?

Comment: I'm looking at the code for these classes.  I don't understand it all, but if you use `PathIterator`, a `Line2D` returns an iterator that returns just one line segment, while a `Rectangle2D` returns an iterator that returns four.  It looks like `intersect` relies on a private `curves` variable that is created by calling  `getPathIterator`, which leaves me doubtful that this will work.

Comment: Do you need this to work for `Area` objects?  That is, do you need an `isColliding` method that works with things other than lines and rectangles?  If not, `Line2D` has its own `intersects` method that tests whether the line intersects the rectangle (a `Rectangle2D`, specifically, but `Rectangle` extends `Rectangle2D` so it should work with that too).

Comment: OK, then you probably need a way to keep the `Line2D` and the `Rectangle`.  (You can't get them back from an `Area` if you use them in the `new Area(Shape s)` constructor.)  So either keep them as `Line2D` and `Rectangle` instead of `Area`, or if necessary define a new class that can hold both.

Comment: Oh my, I actually need to collide the line with an area, it's made of a bunch of different rectangles. My apologies. Is this possible still?

Comment: Please see my edit.  I'm not sure whether it works, but it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @ajb I have found a solution based on yours if you would like to look at it. Maybe you could help me make it more efficient as well. If you post it as an answer I will gladly give you credit, you gave me the idea after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by making a recursive function that checks points along the thing.
The higher you set the depth the more accurately it will check, but will take longer to complete. I have been using 10 as my depth (which I believe checks 2047 points along the line) and I encountered no performance loss. Unless your Area object contains really thin parts I don't believe you will need more than this.

Someone feel free to comment and revise my method if you believe you can improve it in any way :)

Thanks to ajb for his suggestion of using a PathIterator which gave me the idea to check points along the line.

```
public static boolean findPoints(Area area1, Line2D line1, int depth) {

    Point p1 = new Point((int) (line1.getX2() + line1.getX1()) / 2,
            (int) (line1.getY2() + line1.getY1()) / 2);

    if (depth == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    pointMiddle = new Point(p1);
    if (area1.contains(p1)) {
        return true;

    } else {
        return findPoints(area1, new Line2D.Double(p1, line1.getP2()),
                depth - 1)
                || findPoints(area1, new Line2D.Double(line1.getP1(), p1),
                        depth - 1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, as you say in the comments, you know that you will always be checking a `Line2D` and a `Rectangle` for collision, you can use the `intersects` method of `Line2D` (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html#intersects-java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D-)):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    Line2D line2 = new Line2D.Double(0, 0, 100, 100);

    System.out.println(isColliding(rect1, line2));
}

public static boolean isColliding(Rectangle2D rect1, Line2D line2) {
    if (line2 != null) {
        return line2.intersects(rect1);
    }   
    return false;    
}
```

To test if a line collides with a more general `Area` is more difficult; I don't think there's a method in the library for this.  If the `Area` is built up of rectangles, you could try saving an array (or `List`) of the `Rectangle` objects, and testing whether the line intersects with any of them.  Another approach: You can try using the `contains` method of `Area`, which tests whether an area contains a point.  If *either* endpoint of the `Line2D` is contained by the `Area`, then the line and the area collide.  If both endpoints are outside the area, but the area consists of straight lines (`area.isPolygonal()`), you could retrieve each line segment from the polygon and test whether the line intersects each line segment.  You can do this with `area.getPathIterator(null)`, and then using something like this on the resulting path iterator:

```
double[] coords = new double[6];
double moveX, moveY, prevX, prevY, newX, newY;
while (!pathIterator.isDone()) {
    switch (pathIterator.currentSegment(coords)) {
        case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
             moveX = coords[0];  moveY = coords[1];
             prevX = moveX;  prevY = moveY;
             break;
        case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
             newX = coords[0];  newY = coords[1];
             if ([line2 intersects the line from (prevX,prevY) to (newX,newY)]) {
                 return true;
             }
             prevX = newX; prevY = newY;
             break;
        case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
        case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
             throw new RuntimeException("What is a curve doing in my rectangle?");
        case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
             // go back to the last SEG_MOVETO point, usually the first point
             if ([line2 intersects the line from (prevX,prevY) to (moveX,moveY)]) {
                 return true;
             }
             prevX = newX; prevY = newY;
             break;
    }
}
```

There are methods in `Line2D` to test whether a line segment intersects another.

**Note:** I have not tested this at all.  I hope it works.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work. I have never worked with an PathIterator before, so that might be why. I will leave this here in case someone else is able to confirm that this works. 

I was able to solve my particular problem by making a recursive function to check the points along the line and using the .contains(Point p) method that can be called by an Area object.

Comment: @SamBurns Well, as I said, I didn't test it.  I'll need to try it when I can find the time, and if I can get it to work, I'll post a more complete answer.  So in effect you divided the line into some number of small segments and checked each point?  That should work in most cases--you'd have to have a polygon with an extremely narrow part to make that approach fail.  I thought about that approach too, but I thought the `PathIterator` approach would be faster.

Comment: Its pretty quick because it will stop checking once it finds it, so most of the time on mine it completes in like 4 or less checks.